# In the Yesod ecosystem, what is the best way to urlencode some Text?

Tags: haskell, urlencode, yesod

I'd like to url-encode some Text (e.g., replace each space with a %20, etc.). I found "HTTP" Network.HTTP.Base.urlEncode and could use that, but I'm wondering if there's something else that's normally used in the Yesod ecosystem.

Comment: After some hunting, I found that "http-conduit" Network.HTTP.Conduit.parseUrl uses (escapeURIString isAllowedInURI) from "network" Network.URI.  Is this what other Yesod'ers use?

Comment: Grep'ing through the code, I found that joinPath in Yesod.hs uses Network.HTTP.Types.encodePath/encodePathSegments to create paths, which does the percent escaping, amongst other things....  This is for creating percent escaped urls from a parsed path object though (not from Text).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to the complexity of URL escaping, the real answer is "it depends." There are slightly different rules for the percent encoding of path segments and query strings, for example.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to encode, but I'd recommend sticking to the http-types package. One place to start would be [urlEncode](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.9/http-types-0.12.2/Network-HTTP-Types-URI.html#v:urlEncode), though there are many other functions in that packages (such as `encodePathSegments` mentioned by @jamshidh) which are worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks Michael and jamshidh!

Comment: For more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704839/discrepancies-of-percent-encoding-for-urls